# Python heapq not being pushed in right order?

Tags: python

util.py

```
import heapq
class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap=[]

    def push(self,item,priority):
        pair = (priority,item)
        heapq.heappush(self.heap,pair)

    def pop(self):
        (priority,item) = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        return item

    def getHeap(self):
        return self.heap

Class PriorityQueueWithFunction(PriorityQueue):
    def __init__ (self,priorityFunction):
        self.priorityFunction = priorityFunction
        PriorityQueue.__init__(self)

    def push(self,item):
        PriorityQueue.push(self, item, self.priorityFunction(item))
```

pqtest.py

```
import os,sys
lib_path = os.path.abspath('../../lib/here')
sys.path.append(lib_path)

import Util
import string
import random

def str_gen():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(random.randint(2,8)))

def pqfunc(item):
    return len(str(item))

rdy = Util.PriorityQueueFunction(pqfunc)
for i in range(1,10):
    rdy.push(str_gen())

for i in rdy.getHeap():
    print i
```

it printed

```
(3, '2UA')
(4, '6FD6')
(6, 'DLB66A')          <---out of place
(4, 'J97K')
(7, 'GFQMRZZ')         <----out of place
(6, 'SRU5T4')
(7, 'BP4PGKH')
(7, 'CBUJWQO')
(7, '5KNNY1P')
```

why are those two out of place and how to fix?

and when I add print `rdy.pop()` inside  `for i in rdy.getHeap():`
it only pops 5 of them when i pushed in 9

Comment: is that wrong? @BurhanKhalid  you heapq.heappush(self.heap,obj)

Comment: @ealeon - quick look at it only but, are you sometimes mixing up the order of priority/item?

Comment: @azhrei the order in which it is being pushed is random. its pq's job to sort them in order based on priority. right??? isnt that the whole point of using pq so that i dont have to order myself.

Comment: @ealeon That's not what I was getting at, but irrelevant now that you have your answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) functions do not keep your list *sorted*, but only guarantee that the *heap property* is maintained:

- `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]`
- `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]`

Consequently, `heap[0]` is always the smallest item.

When you want to iterate over the items in order of priority, you cannot simply iterate over the heap but need to `pop()` items off until the queue is empty.  `heappop()` will take the first item, then reorganize the list to fulfil the heap invariant.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: is it possible to have it so that heap[0] is the largest item?

Comment: @ealeon `heapq` always keeps a min-heap and uses `<` for comparison.  To get a max-heap, you can easily negate your priorities.  In your test example, just use `-len()` as the priority.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list in order you can use heapq's nsmallest and nlargest functions.

> heapq.nsmallest(len(my_heap), my_heap) - list smallest to largest
>
> heapq.nlargest(len(my_heap), my_heap) - list largest to smallest